# How can I create link with Twig in label for form

Tags: twig, symfony4

How can I create a link / path in label in this case:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_widget(form.gdpr, { 'label': 'Terms' }) }}
</div>
```

Something like that:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_widget(form.gdpr, { 'label': '<a href="...">Terms</a>' }) }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twig has a function, `form_label()` that allows you to specify a label for a form element. Nothing stops you to wrap this label into a `<a>` tag :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <a href="{{ path("the_route_name_of_the_link") }}">{{ form_label(form.gdpr, 'Terms') }}</a>
    {{ form_widget(form.gdpr) }}
</div>
```

For more informations, see the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#form-rendering-variables)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why but {{ form_label(form.gdpr, 'Terms') }} doesn't work in my case :(